How to disable popup, asking permission for notifications using ADB on Andriod app launch
Whenever appium launches the app (simulator ) , i am getting popup "Allow app to send you notifications". I want to suppress this popup permanently in simulator ( better if it is on package level ).
I have already tried adb shell pm revoke in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS using answer.
I am using Mac M1. I am sure i was able to supress this popup in past on mac intel chip using adb command. For clarity attaching screenshot.


Not sure if its a good answer but one way to handle it with capabilities is
autoGrantPermissions: true, this will just click allow for any popup ever.

@mosaad I appreciate for this suggestion, but this will be problematic if app throws a pop ( not related to notifications ) and test case demands to reject it.
